# PHP maximum number of repositories

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

so I am developing a web app in php using Laravel framework. I have 12 Models and 1 Controller, and 12 Repositories linking to models. In each repository I am writing some functions with queries, so they are not repeated in controller. I am trying to inject repositories in controller constructor, and don't know how many of them are too many?

I heard, its 1 or 2  usualy, but I have 12 of them so far.

Controller:

```
class PagesController extends Controller   {
    protected $review;
    protected $organization;
    protected $user;
    protected $city; 
    protected $buyer;
    protected $employee;

    public function __construct(ReviewRepository $review, OrganizationRepository $organization, UserRepository $user, CityRepository $city, BuyerRepository $buyer, EmployeeRepository $employee) { //here are just 6 repositories, I have much more
        $this->employee = $employee;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->buyer = $buyer;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->organization = $organization;
        $this->review = $review;
}
```

Repository:

```
class ReviewRepository {

protected $review;

function __construct(Review $review)
{
    $this->review = $review;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said in a comment, too many is subjective. However, if you find yourself asking this question that probably means there is something worth rethinking. This is again highly subjective.

From my standpoint, and my understanding of MVC, the whole point of Repositories is separation of concerns. Perhaps your Controller is responsible for more that it should be?

In the application we built, we decided to use Repositories as containers for business logic. This isn't the traditional pattern but you will find that any design pattern will often end up bent or broken in certain circumstances.

The question is: does your `PageController` really need visibility on `ReviewsRepository`, `BuyerRepository`, `CityRepository`, etc? Or could you encapsulate this logic into a `PageRepository` class which would then be responsible for providing the proper data that your `PageController` required? Further, you could move different related repositories into their own parent repo that abstracts away the more complex parts of this to further reduce your dependencies.

**So the moral of the story is when I find myself asking "is this too much?", that usually means I need to look at abstracting. It doesn't mean you have to, but taking a step back never hurts.**